# When are tensor products isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Suppose we have vector spaces $V_1,...,V_n$ and $W_1,...,W_m$. Are there any conditions such that the following isomorphism holds?

$$ \bigotimes_{i=1}^nV_i \cong \bigotimes_{j=1}^mW_j$$

Comment: In the finite dimensional case, this holds if and only if 
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n \dim(V_i) = \prod_{j = 1}^m \dim(W_j)
$$

Comment: Is there anything that can be said in the infinite-dimensional case?

Comment: Exactly the content of the answer given (assuming the axiom of choice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $\{v_{ij}\}_{J_i}$ is a basis for $V_i,$ then 
$$\{{v_{1j}}_1\otimes\cdots\otimes{v_{nj}}_n\}_{J_1\times\cdots\times J_n}$$ is a basis for $\bigotimes_{i=1}^n V_i,$ so $$\text{dim}\left(\bigotimes_{i=1}^nV_i\right)=\text{cardinality}(J_1\times\cdots \times J_n).$$
If $I_i$ is a basis for $W_i$, then by similar logic 
$$\text{dim}\left(\bigotimes_{i=1}^mW_i\right)=\text{cardinality}(I_1\times\cdots\times I_m).$$
So the two vector spaces are isomorphic iff $$\text{cardinality}(J_1\times\cdots\times J_n)=\text{cardinality}(I_1\times \cdots\times I_m).$$